# .NET MVC4 DropDownListFor using foreign key behaving strangely

Tags: .net, drop-down-menu

First of all, I'm new to .NET MVC, although I've worked with the general MVC idea before.  I'm using .NET MVC4 with CodeFirst using the Entity Framework.

I'm trying to add a simple dropdown to a "Create" view to allow users to select a foreign key which relates to another model.

Here's the relevant code:

From the view (PropertyProgram/Create):

```
<div class="editor-field">
    @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Program.ID, new SelectList(ViewBag.Programs, "Id","Name"));
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Program.ID);
</div>
```

From the controller (PropertyProgramController):

```
public ActionResult Create()
{
    ViewBag.Programs = db.Programs;
    return View();
}
```

from the model (PropertyProgram):

```
public class PropertyProgram
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual Program Program { get; set; }
}
```

The view works correctly and the correct data is displayed in the dropdown, but for some reason, after the post, a new row is created in the Program table in the database with null fields for everything except ID.  The expected behavior would be for the created PropertyProgram row to have the Program ID selected on the dropdown be placed into the Program_ID column in the database.  Any idea why this isn't behaving as expected?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Of course ten minutes after I write up this question, I figure out the answer!  So apparently in the entity framework, having a virtual link is not enough, you also have to have an ID that points to the table as well.  I simply added this line of code to the PropertyProgram model:

```
public int ProgramId { get; set; }
```

After adding this, I created a migration, and then I changed the dropdown code to this:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.ProgramId, new SelectList(ViewBag.Programs, "Id", "Name"));
```

After this, everything is working correctly!  I'm not 100% sure WHY exactly this fixed things, but it did.  If anyone would care to explain why, I would greatly appreciate it.